# ASP.NET MVC pass selected IEnumerable items to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

My view:

```
@model IEnumarable<MyViewModel>

...

<table>
foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.IsSelected)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)</td>
    ...
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

I need to pass all selected items to MyAction using Html.ActionLink() if it is possible.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't `model.Where(x => x.IsSelected)` sufficient?

Comment: @JakubJankowski He's trying to post the values back to the controller

Comment: Yes, but if he creates suitable method for POST, isn't the LINQ expression above sufficient to do it? The OP has not stated any other requirements.

Comment: Why do you want to  pass all selected items to `Action` using `Html.ActionLink()` ?

Comment: @Div it is not necessary, but would be nice.

Comment: @JakubJankowski no, it's not working for me.

Comment: @user2089322, How ?

Comment: @Div for now it should works :). I suggest I can use BeginFrom, but submit button should placed outside <form> element, so I'm not sure that it is possible.

Comment: *but submit button should placed outside <form> element,* In that case you can use ajax.

Comment: @Div thanks for the tip. I'm not sure that I did it all right, but it works for me. I've just take all data from html via js and send it to my controller.